# What does new() mean in this context

Tags: c#, generics

What does new() mean in the following context:

```
 public interface ISpecification<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class,new()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a constraint on the type parameter `TEntity` that specifies that it must have a public parameterless constructor.

See [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

Comment: why we want to impose that it has a parameterless constructor?

Answer (score 4):

It means you can construct the class with a parameterless public constructor. Or, it lets you do `var entity= new TEntity();` without the compiler having fits.